# Override error settings on PHP target?

Tags: haxe

By default, the [Haxe PHP target](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/1ae448228d0fba1edc2c0712d71825fe0cb660a1/std/php/Boot.hx#L864) sets the error reporting level to the maximum setting and overrides the default error handler:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
set_error_handler('_hx_error_handler', E_ALL);
set_exception_handler('_hx_exception_handler');
```

I'm writing a PHP library that is intended to be used within a larger codebase and overriding the error handling like this is seriously problematic.  I'm aware that I can [rollback the error handling settings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.restore-error-handler.php) but that means resetting the error handler every time the codebase is called. This forces a fairly functional style and makes async much more complicated.  I could comment out those lines, but I would prefer to not rely on monkey patching.

Is there a compiler flag I can pass to specify the error reporting level?  Can I somehow prevent the error handling overrides from leaking into code that uses my library?